# 1.py script convertd to exe using cx_Freeze not working on windows

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, windows-8.1, cx-freeze

I have written a basic python gui.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk(className ="My first GUI")
foo = Label(root,text="Hello World")

foo.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Now I want that this .py script runs on windows systems without python as well. I used cx_freeze module for this and created a setup.py file like this

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["Tkinter"], "excludes": []}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win64":
    base = "Win64GUI"

setup(  name = "guiDemo",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "My GUI application!",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("guiDemo.py", base=base)])
```

I am running this script as

> > python setup.py build

The output build directory as a exe file but when copy the whole folder and run it on a Windows system (Win 8.1 pro mainly) I see this

[Win 8.1 pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCg8x.png)

Also ran it on ubuntu using Wine and got this -

> > wine: Bad EXE format

What am I doing wrong ?

Using ubuntu 14.04